# Monitoring Log-Shipping for Multiple Databases

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, monitoring

We are setting up log-shipping for multiple databases hosted at different server and while process began, I noticed that only one SQL job is being retained at Monitoring Server.

Our plan was to have one monitoring server which will be monitoring all the replication between Production and DR for databases and we can set-up alert in case any of the replication goes bad.

Kindly suggest how to make multiple jobs possible on the monitoring server.

Comment: Kindly let me know in case question is not clear or require more info to get expert advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending considerable amount of time in setting up log-shipping for multiple database and trying to figure out why only one alert job gets created - had no clue on why however one thing became clearer as we kept on configuring databases and jobs were getting over-written that even though there is only one job being retained at SQL Server Agent Job level, it does its job for all databases and alerts us in case any of the underlying database replication fails or has some issue in back-up, copy or restoration.

I am not sure why MSSQL doesn't support having multiple jobs created however its doing its intended job internally. I also have been checking "Transaction Log Shipping Status" report can monitor the status of all databases.

I also checked two tables from msdb database at monitoring server and ensured that log-shipping is working as expected.

[image: Log Shipping Monitoring Table at Primary and Secondary]

Thank you for your support. This could be helpful to somebody who is setting up log-shipping for the very first time and wants to use monitoring server.